# How To Import app/index.js instead of app?

Tags: angular, systemjs

**How can I configure systemjs to download *app/index.js* instead of *app/*?**

I'm developing an angular2 application. When I test it with *ng* it works perfectly. But then I test it in the deployment server (a python webserver) I got an error. *main.js* tries to download *app* and the server returns an empty response and not *app/index.js*.

Since I don't have control over the webserver, I'm trying to map systemjs to get *app/index.js* instead of *app/*. I've tried adding this configuration to system-config.js:

```js
var map = {
    'app': 'app/index.js'
};

// ...

System.config({ map: map, packages: packages });
```

But it doesn't do anything. Also, I tried with:

```js
var packages = {
  'app': {
    main: 'index'
  }
};

// ...

System.config({ map: map, packages: packages });
```

And nothing, they don't cause any effect.

Comment: i dont know it's correct way. but can you try give full path in your html main import   System.import('app/index.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });

Comment: Thank you, Ravin, that'll do it! If you wan to add a reply, I can mark it as the preferred answer.

Comment: ok i will do. but i am sure some better way will be there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give full path in your html as below

```
System.import('app/index.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```